# How to remove a child element from a parent without affecting a DOM

Tags: jquery

I have  div structure like below,

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>

<div class="child">
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

i 've select the parent by `var ele = $(".parent");`

How do i remove a ".child" div from the "ele" variable without affecting the DOM, So that

i can query like `$(".div1", ele)`, which will not return two .div1

Note:

The above is a simple sample example, but in my project i've very huge amount of div like div1

So i want to do operation like below,

```
var ele = $(".parent");
ele.each(function(){
         var g = $(this);
      var val1 = $(".div1", g);
      var val1 = $(".div2", g);
      var val1 = $(".div3", g);
      var val1 = $(".div4", g);
});
```

Please give me shortest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your selector to `ele.children('.div1')` you will only get the first `.div1` that is a direct descendant of `.parent`

However since what you actually asked for was how to remove elements from a selector without changing the dom the answer is [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.... you need to fine tune your selector

```
$(".div1:not(.child .div1)", ele)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fywYm/)

or

```
ele.children('.div1')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Rf2C/)

Comment: or `$("> .div1", ele);`

Comment: Thanks, actually i want find a div which is inside a .parent and not inside (.parent .child)

Comment: @sathishkumar that is what the above will give you... did you check the fiddles